# react native Keychain throw error in xiaomi redmi 9c

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, react-native-keychain

I build the app but after I try to login I get an error related to react native keychain.
In another phone, it works fine but in Xiaomi redmi9c it throws an error. I don't understand why and I could find much information about it.
Here is the error I get

```
Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.oblador.keychain.cipherStorage.CipherStorageFacebookConceal.throwIfInsufficientLevel(com.oblador.keychain.SecurityLevel)' on a null object reference
```

How to solve this? why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try running it by clearing cache..`npm start --reset-cache && react-native run-android`

Comment: @RahmanHaroon, your suggestion didn't work for me, I still got the same error.